# Visa questions regarding extension and entry

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I have a tier 2 general visa which expires on 30/09/16.

I needed to extend the visa, so recently I applied the visa in while I was on vacation in my home country( outside UK). So the visa got approved, and I got a new visa sticker (vignette) which is valid from15/09/16-14/10/16.

However, my airplane arrives in UK at 31/08/16.

Can I enter UK on the date? The date 31 Aug is before the valid start date for new visa, while it is also before the expire date of my old visa.

is my old visa still valid at 31/08/16? Or is it no longer valid since I got a new one? I am curious whether I must postpone my airplane or not... ( If I have to postpone, it will also cause some trouble for my job..)

Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: Did they cancel your old visa?  If they didn't stamp it as "cancelled" then I suppose it's still valid.

Answer (score 1):

[According to TSE resident expert, @GayotFow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92292/can-i-have-two-uk-visas-simultaneously)

> The UK works like Schengen does in that overlapping time periods are not allowed. This is a matter of policy and not spelled out in the rules. The policy is that only one type of permission can be valid at a time.
>
> What happens is that the issuing post will curtail the existing visa so that it ends before the new one starts.